# Get the value of a defaultdict

Tags: python

I read data from a bunch or emails and count frequency of each word. first construct two counters:

```
counters.form = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

Get the frequency by

```
for word in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]\w*', data):
    counters.form[word][file_name] += 1
```

For each form, there is a counter that store all the emails which this word appears in, and the frequency of the form in this email. e.g.

```
form = {'a':   {'email1':4, 'email2':3}, 
        'the': {'email1':2, 'email3':4},
        'or':  {'email1':2, 'email3':1}}
```

How to get the frequency of a certain form in a certain email? the frequency of `a` in `email2` is 3.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Maybe you could give a small example?

Comment: do you have to use `defaultdict` because it is homework? `collections.Counter` would be more suitable

Comment: @gnibbler when I use collections.Counter, it tells me the object is not iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're building what the IR (information retrieval) community calls an inverted index.  In that case, I agree with the overall approach you're taking, but also recommend that you use the counter class **in conjunction with** default dict...

```py
counters.form = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
```

`counters.form` would then act as a sort of index of a compressed world model, where absence of observations isn't an error (nor False), just 0.

Using your `form` data as an example, we populate the inverted index like...

```
#-- Build the example data into the proposed structure...
counters.form['a'].update({'email1':4, 'email2':3})
counters.form['the'].update({'email1':2, 'email3':4})
counters.form['or'].update({'email1':2, 'email3':1}})
```

Now, to get the frequency of a form in this data, we dereference like it was a 2d array...

```
print counters.form['a']['email2']
```

...which should print `3` and is more-or-less the same as the structure you are currently using.  The real difference of these two approaches is when you have no observations.  For instance...

```
print counters.form['noword']['some-email']
```

...using your current structure (`collections.defaultdict(dict)`), the get of 'noword' on the `counters.form` would 'miss' and the defaultdict would automatically associate a newly constructed, empty dictionary to `counters.form['noword']`; however, when this empty dict is then queried for the key: 'some-email', the empty dict has no such key, resulting in a `KeyError` exception for 'some-email'

If instead we use the suggested structure (`collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)`), then the get of 'noword' on `counters.form` would miss, and a new `collections.Counter` would be associated to the key 'noword'.  When the counter is then queried (in the second dereference) for 'some-email', the counter will respond 0 -- which is (I believe) the desired behavior.

Some other recipes...

```
#-- Show distinct emails which contain 'someword'
emails = list(counters.form['someword'])

#-- Show tally of all observations of 'someword'
tally = sum(counters.form['someword'].values( ))
```

Comment: What if I want to write a for loop to go through everything? Should I use `for token in counters.form.items():`

Comment: @juju counters.form.items( ) will return a list of tuples of the form [('a', <counter>), ('the', <counter>), ...] which is amenable to the list processing functions like map, filter, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class instead of a `defaultdict`:

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Comment: The approach here loses the information about the sources of the counts.  juju asks "How to get the frequency of a certain form in a certain email?", which with only a counter (and no other supplementary indexing dicts, etc.) cannot answer that question.